# Como obter o conjunto de todos os argumentos em Python?

Tags: python, parâmetros, reflexão

Python possui tanto parâmetros posicionais e nomeados quanto operadores `*` e `**` que permitem receber um número arbitrário de argumentos adicionais:

```
def foo(a, b, c=1, *args, **kwargs):
    print(a, b, c, args, kwargs)

foo(1, 2)          # 1, 2, 1, (), {}
foo(1, 2, 3)       # 1, 2, 3, (), {}
foo(1, 2, 3, 4)    # 1, 2, 3, (4,), {}
foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) # 1, 2, 3, (4,5), {}

foo(b=1, a=2)                # 2, 1, 1, (), {}
foo(b=1, a=2, c=3)           # 2, 1, 3, (), {}
foo(b=1, a=2, c=3, d=4)      # 2, 1, 3, (), {'d':4}
foo(b=1, a=2, c=3, d=4, e=5) # 2, 1, 3, (), {'d':4, 'e':5}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, d=6, e=7) # 1 2 3 (4, 5) {'d': 6, 'e': 7}
```

Gostaria de saber se, num caso como esse, que mistura parâmetros explicitamente declarados com listas/conjuntos de argumentos arbitrários, se é possível obter o conjunto de **todos eles**, e não apenas os adicionais. Exemplo:

```
def foo(a, b, c=1, *args, **kwargs):
    print(list_args(...))
    print(dict_args(...))

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, d=6, e=7)
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
# {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 3:4, 4:5, 'd':6, 'e':7}
```

(apenas um exemplo; uma funcionalidade desse tipo poderia ter restrições adicionais - como não misturar `*args` com `**kwargs`, ou representar os argumentos de uma forma diferente - mas o interessante é que algo assim existisse/pudesse ser feito)

É possível? Compare com a linguagem JavaScript, que permite tanto parâmetros nomeados quanto o acesso à lista de todos os argumentos via `arguments`:

```js
function foo(a, b, c) {
    console.log(arguments);
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    // Repare que o conjunto inclui "a", "b" e "c", ao contrário do Python
```

Nota: a motivação dessa pergunta é achar um meio de criar uma função que possua um conjunto bem definido de parâmetros (com número e nomes exatos, e talvez valores opcionais) mas possa repassar todos eles (após alguma validação, ou mesmo alteração) a uma outra função que possua exatamente os mesmos parâmetros.

Comment: Juro que ainda não entendi a motivação disso. Se é tudo exato, por que precisa fazer esse tipo de validação?

Comment: @PabloPalácios A motivação é auxiliar na criação de [decoradores](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator) (o padrão de design, não necessariamente [a construção sintática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintaxe_e_sem%C3%A2ntica_de_Python#Decoradores)). Um exemplo prático - não necessariamente o melhor - seria criar uma função com assinatura idêntica à de um modelo no Django, validar os dados recebidos (regras de negócio) e em seguida repassar tudo ao `objects.create` sem ter de listar explicitamente cada argumento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer:

```
import inspect

def func(a, b, c):
    frame = inspect.currentframe() #equivalente a sys._getframe(0)
    args_names, _, _, locals_ = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    args = [locals_[i] for i in args_names]
    kwargs = dict(zip(args_names, args))
    print "args: %r" %args
    print "kwargs: %r" %kwargs


>>> func(1, 2, 3)
args: [1, 2, 3]
kwargs: {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

>>> func(c=1, a=2, b=3)
args: [2, 3, 1]
kwargs: {'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3}
```

Você pode fazer uma função que faz o dump dos argumentos:

```
import sys
import inspect

def dumpargs():
    frame = sys._getframe(1) # 0: funcao atual, 1: pega a funcao anterior na pilha
    args_names, _, _, locals_ = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    args = [locals_[i] for i in args_names]
    kwargs = dict(zip(args_names, args))
    return args, kwargs


def outra(a, b, c, d=1):
    args, kwargs = dumpargs()
    print "kwargs: %r" %kwargs
    print "args: %r" %args

>>> outra(1, 2, 3)
kwargs: {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
args: [1, 2, 3, 1]

>>> outra(1, 2, 3, 4)
kwargs: {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
args: [1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> outra(b=1, c=2, d=3, a=4)
kwargs: {'a': 4, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 3}
args: [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

## Atualização 01

Como notado pelo autor da pergunta, parte desse código só tem garantia de  funcionar em CPython. [`sys._getframe`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe), por exemplo, é específica do CPython não há garantia de funcionar em PyPy, Jython ou outra implementação do python. Além disso, [`inspect.getargvalues`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargvalues) está *deprecated* desde o python 3.5

## Atualização 02

O código funciona em `PyPy 2.6.0 (python 2.7.9)` e no `Jython 2.7.0`

Comment: Muito bom! Algumas dessas funções estão obsoletas (*deprecated*), e outras são dependentes de implementação, mas testei esse código no CPython 3.4 e funcionou corretamente. Alguns ajustes podem ser interessantes dependendo do caso (por exemplo, noto que você ignorou dois valores no `getargvalues`, de modo que ele desconsidera `*args` e `**kwargs`), mas no geral parece tudo ok.

Comment: @mgibsonbr getargvalues está obsoleta mesmo (desde python 3.5), mas você não falou a versão do python. Eu também ainda não me interessei em programar para o python3k, apesar de estar por dentro da nova implementação e mudanças. Ainda não fiz isso pq a maioria do código que dou suporte ainda depende do python 2.5 (nem 2.7 é)

Comment: Eu também continuo trabalhando no 2.7 (muito código legado que daria trabalho migrar), e também restrito ao CPython, então sua resposta está perfeita pra mim. Mas achei importante deixar essa nota caso alguém que use Python 3.5+ ou Jython, PyPy, IronPython etc esteja ciente das limitações (pois também o `currentframe` [pode não estar disponível](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe), bem como o [`sys._getframe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe)).

Comment: Eu testei, funciona no `PyPy 2.6.0 (python 2.7.9)` e no `Jython 2.7.0`. Não funciona no `IronPython 2.7.5`, este não implementa nem `sys._getframe` nem `inspect.getargvalues`

Comment: Testar https://stackoverflow.com/a/10974508/1522342 ao invés de `sys._getframe(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Eu não estou certo sobre o que você realmente quer, no entanto, acredito que possuo uma abordagem mais simples.

Experimentou chamar `locals` logo no início da função?

```
def foo(a, b, c=1, *args, **kw):
    assinatura = locals()
    print(assinatura)


In [5]: foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, d=6, e=7)
{'kw': {'d': 6, 'e': 7}, 'args': (4, 5), 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Caso precise de algo mais preciso, sugiro que utilize o método `getfullargspec` do módulo `inspect`. Ele te retornará todas as informações sobre os parâmetros da função, que poderão ser comparados com o resultado de `locals`.

Comment: Acho que não há muita diferença entre sua resposta e a proposta inicial dele (contida na pergunta): `print(a, b, c, args, kwargs)` a não ser evitar escrever cada argumento.

Comment: @iuridiniz *Caso precise de algo mais preciso, sugiro que utilize o método getfullargspec do módulo inspect. Ele te retornará todas as informações sobre os parâmetros da função, que poderão ser comparados com o resultado de locals* que, no fim das contas dá no mesmo que sua resposta, a exceção é não utilizar funções depreciadas. Além disso, se se quer algo rápido, acredito que `locals` seja um simples atalho.